# Web.xml ignored

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, web.xml

I have an application running on tomcat on a ubuntu server. The problem is that apparently the web.xml file is being ignored. The URL I want to run is throwing a 404 error.

I have the following configuration in my web.xml

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>GAMOAuthSignIn</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>artech.security.api.agamextauthinput</servlet-class>                                                                        
</servlet>
```

and this

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>GAMOAuthSignIn</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/oauth/gam/signin</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

So, when I go to http://example.com:8080/Application/oauth/gam/signin It should run the class file artech.security.api.agamextauthinput that resides on a jar that exists on the App/web-inf/lib folder

Note: When I run the app on windows with the same configurations it works as expected.

Does anyone have experience with this issue? What am I missing?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was putting the web.xml file on the root folder of the application. My bad. Sorry about that. Thanks for the help =)